# combining parameters from an array field in Solrj

Tags: java, solrj

I have data index in Solr. One parameter is an array and looks like this:

```
<arr name="sm_vid_Code_of_Federal_Regulations">
    <str>Section 1.13</str>
    <str>Subpart A</str>
    <str>Part 1</str>
    <str>Subtitle A</str>
    <str>Title 7</str>
    </arr>
```

I need to restrict the results using two or more of these fields.

I tried the following but it does not seem to be working correctly:

```
params.set("fq", "(sm_vid_Code_of_Federal_Regulations:\"Part " + "1" +"\")" + " OR " 
            + "(sm_vid_Code_of_Federal_Regulations:\"Title " + "7" +"\")");
```

Is this the right approach to combine elements from a field array?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I should use the class SolrQuery and the method addField.

So the correct code will be:

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.addFilterQuery("(sm_vid_Code_of_Federal_Regulations:\"Title " + "7" +"\")",  
"(sm_vid_Code_of_Federal_Regulations:\"Part " + "1" +"\")");
```

You can add apply multiple query filters using the addFilterQuery method.

I am very grateful to the anonymous person who wrote the fantastic Solr tutorial:http://www.solrtutorial.com/solrj-tutorial.html